# Solving a variable in a matrix equation?

Tags: matrices, euler-mascheroni-constant

I am having trouble solving for a in the problem below. [image: Problem]

I've simplified it down to: $e^{14} = ln(e^e \cdot a)$. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is the problem assuming the matrix-valued exponential and logarithmic functions, or are they expecting you to plug in the determinants of those matrices into the exponential and logarithm?

Comment: It's assuming the matrix valued exponential/logarithmic functions.

Comment: From what you have written it seems like you're taking the determinants of those matrices.  For reference, the matrix-valued exponential is more like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe

$$
e^{14} \;\; =\;\; \ln(e^e a) \;\; =\;\; \ln e^e  +\ln a \;\; =\;\; e + \ln a
$$

thus $\frac{1}{\ln a} = \frac{1}{e^{14} - e}$.  Assuming NOTA stands for "none of the above" that should be your answer.